# php string-manipulation (clear the "_" and the timestamp)

Tags: php, string

I cant find the way how to strip the useless section of my string (read from SQL)
I've tried the strreplace and truncate but those was not good at all.

I've got a string variable called $stuff

if **$stuff = 145_timestamp** i want to clear the _ and the chars after it. so i want to **$stuff be 145** only. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, i know its a newbie question, but i simply can't find a solution in the php manual. A link will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), which will split a string into an array based on a delimiter. If you use `_` as the delimiter, then you can pick the first value from the array using [current](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```
$number = current(explode("_", $stuff));
```

Comment: This is the most inefficient way to do it - explode goes to all the effort of constructing an array of values, but these are never used. It's 10 times slower than murugaperumal's int cast suggestion.

Comment: Premature optimization and so on... :p

Answer (score 4):

I ran some benchmarks over the various methods suggested here, adding a few suggestions of my own - these are the timings for 100000 iterations of each method

```
int cast     :  79.45ms
intval       : 394.39ms
strtok       : 428.85ms
preg_replace : 604.68ms
substr       : 719.92ms
explode      : 821.99ms
```

The int cast method wins by a mile, but as noted, you will strip off leading zeros. Intval is a slower method of achieving the same result.

A fast method to get the string *with* a leading zero is to use strtok($str, '_');

```
$str="154_timestamp";
$c=100000;

$s=microtime(true);
for ($x=0; $x<$c; $x++)
    $n=(int)$str;
printf("int cast : %0.2fms\n", (microtime(true)-$s)*1000);

$s=microtime(true);
for ($x=0; $x<$c; $x++)
    $n = current(explode("_", $str));
printf("explode : %0.2fms\n", (microtime(true)-$s)*1000);

$s=microtime(true);
for ($x=0; $x<$c; $x++)
    $n = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '_'));
printf("substr : %0.2fms\n", (microtime(true)-$s)*1000);

$s=microtime(true);
for ($x=0; $x<$c; $x++)
    $n = strtok($str, '_');
printf("strtok : %0.2fms\n", (microtime(true)-$s)*1000);

$s=microtime(true);
for ($x=0; $x<$c; $x++)
    $n = intval($str);
printf("intval : %0.2fms\n", (microtime(true)-$s)*1000);

$s=microtime(true);
for ($x=0; $x<$c; $x++)
     $n = preg_replace("/_[^_]+$/",'',$str);
printf("preg_replace : %0.2fms\n", (microtime(true)-$s)*1000);
```

Comment: @Paul Dixon: good stuff. What about doing the replace/cast in SQL?

Answer (score 3):

```
$stuff = "145_timestamp";
$stuff=(int)$stuff;
print $stuff;
```

Comment: note: if $stuff = "020_timestamp", it will become 20. This may or may not be the same thing as 020.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace("/_[^_]+$/",'',$string);
```

Comment: What if there is more than one `_`?

Answer (score 0):

[intval](http://php.net/intval) fetches the integer value of strings. Or you could use a regular expression or explode:

```
$int = preg_replace('/^(\d+)/', '$1', $string);
$int = explode('_',  $string)[0];
```